# Web reporting library which is not SQL ReportViewer

Tags: google-chrome, reporting-services, webforms, shared-libraries, reportviewer

I deal with ReportViewer and RDLC since 2005.
Ever since that I am failing always in new troubles and problems, It most time working okay but also It sometime give me so much headache.

Common stricture for reporviewer for me is that only working as should work in IE.
So I start wondering is there time to look for other library which can replace ReportViewer.
Most of time I developing business apps, so called ERP.

I am looking for library which can be included in project written in C# asp.net web forms, can also use local resources as printer , paper properties and others, reports should be able to develop separately in different layer.

I know that there is [Report Bulder for Delphi](http://www.digital-metaphors.com/) and I guest that there is other reporting library for asp.net C#. Does Crystal Reports can work on WebForms ?
Are there any other which can bi installed inside Chrome or Firefox as extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can try our [SharpShooter Reports](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/SharpShooter-Reports-Web.aspx). It is optimized for ASP.NET MVC however you can easily add it to any HTML page as it needs only several lines of JS code.